# In play framework 2.5.3, parse a JsValue to a java object

Tags: json, playframework-2.5

my question is very simple, it's that, how can I convert a json to a third-part java `class` which has no method of `apply` and `unapply` but not scala `case class`. The detailed code is like this following

```
def login = Action { implicit request =>
    val jsonBody = request.body.asJson // the jsonBody is value of Option[JsValue]

    val myClass = //some method can be provided to convert the jsonBody to myClass(a third-part java class)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can define a case class like MyCaseClass(a: String, b: Int), and validate the json you get like this:

```
request.body.asJson.validate[MyCaseClass] match {
  case myCaseClass: JsSuccess[MyCaseClass] => new JavaClass(a, b)
  case error: JsError => //handle the error
}
```

Note that you can use `Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>` in order to validate that you have a valid Json object.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but it's not my wants. Another thing, the `parse.json` can only be used when the content-type is `application/json`. when the content-type is not `application/json, the request body will be parsed as None if you use `parse.json`.

Comment: If the content-type is not application/json, you will get an error when doing .asJson. And if it's not your wants, please detail them, because I don't get them.